# Where should I call dispose of ViewModel in UWP after navigating away?

Tags: c#, uwp, navigation

I want to dispose my View Model when user navigates away from the page so it will not retain memory, but I don't know where is the best place I should call the Dispose method.

As far as I know, there are three places I can call Dispose method:

1. `OnNavigatedFrom` in `xaml.cs`
2. Adding event in `xaml` (`Page_Unloaded`) and call the `Dispose` inside there.
3. Registering event handler of `this.Unload` in the View constructor, then call the `Dispose` method there.

From what I read, for option 3 I would need to unsubscribe the event handler because I explicitly register it, while for option 2, it will unsubscribe automatically (based on this [discussion](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues/777)). So I'd rather use the 2nd option.

Is there any other thing I should consider about?

I'm sorry for the obviously noob question. This performance and memory leak thing is tricky, I want to know what is the best practice and the reason behind it. Thank you.

Comment: How and where do you initialize the view model and set the `DataContext` of the page? If you do this in `OnNavigatedTo`, it makes perfect sense to dispose it in `OnNavigatedFrom`. If you inject the view with the view model, it doesn't make much sense to dispose it in the view at all.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can release the `ViewModel`, but the recommended way to do this is to cache.

Here is recommend way:

```cs
public OtherPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
}
```

By caching the current page, the page will not be recreated on the next navigate, which means that no new memory is added.

Best regards.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. For some requirement reason, I cannot implement the NavigationCacheMode.Enabled to all of my pages though. I'm implementing it in some, but for the other pages which I can't, I want to make sure it gets cleaned up properly so even if new memory gets added, the memory increase would be minimal. That's why I was asking how to clean it properly.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but once the page is created, memory usage is difficult to remove. In fact, `Page` class does not provide this method. You need to implement a similar method to minimize memory usage. The `UnLoaded` event and the `OnNavigatedFrom` event are trigged when the current page is not in the Frame, either of these two events can call the Disposed method.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out how some popular MVVM frameworks handle the View Model lifetime. For example MvvmCross maintains the view models for pages which are on the backstack so that they can be quickly activated when navigating back to the view.

This [article](https://blog.rsuter.com/recommendations-best-practices-implementing-mvvm-xaml-net-applications/) on the other hand suggests creating view model instance directly in XAML. This way its lifetime will be tied to the view itself and you can dispose of it when navigating away or when the page is unloaded.

Maybe the easiest solution would be to just use some MVVM framework to make your life simpler.